# Data processing causing poor data integrity via Bluetooth on Android

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, inputstream

I am processing some binary data that I am receiving via bluetooth, however, when a lot of data comes in at once I get missing or invalid bytes in my data stream.  I was hoping someone could help me out with this since I need some help getting a more consistent response.  I am alright with simply "throwing away" bad data.  Here are the relevant methods, they run inside the "Connected" thread:

```
    public void run() {
        Log.i(TAG, "BEGIN mConnectedThread");
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int num_bytes = 0;
        // Keep listening to the InputStream while connected
        while (true) {
            try {
                // Read from the InputStream
                mmInStream.read(buffer, 0, 11);
                processBytes(buffer);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "disconnected", e);
                connectionLost();
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    private void processBytes(byte[] bytes) throws IOException {
        if (bytes[0] != delimiter) {
            int c;
            do {
                c = mmInStream.read();
            } while (c != delimiter && c != -1);
            if (c == -1) {
                return;
            }
        }
        /*Some processing happens here to generate the variables cellId and
                      voltage and cellId2 and voltage2
                    */
        // Send the obtained bytes to the UI Activity
        mHandler.obtainMessage(BluetoothInterface.DATA_READ,
                new DataPoint(cellId, voltage)).sendToTarget();
        // Send the obtained bytes to the UI Activity
        mHandler.obtainMessage(BluetoothInterface.DATA_READ,
                new DataPoint(cellId2, voltage2)).sendToTarget();

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I've had that problem before. I not quite sure if I solved it by read the stream into a string object before calling processBytes.